# RegEx for selecting the first element of a path

Tags: regex, path

My question is pretty simple, I would like to write a RegEx that does this:

`/ -> /`

`/foo -> /foo`

`/foo/bar -> /foo`

`/foo/bar/baz -> /foo`

I've tried this:

`replace(/(\/[^\/]*)\/[^\/]*/, '$1')`

But it returns the path, unmodified.

Does anyone know how to do?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This should work:

```
/^\/[^\/]*/
```

It will match the start slash and all chars until another slash is found (excepting the 2nd slash)

```
'/test'.match(/^\/[^\/]+/)[0]
```

will return '/test'

```
'/test/asd'.match(/^\/[^\/]+/)[0]
```

will return '/test'

Strings that don't start with a slash will not match.

Answer (score 1):

To replace the entire string the regex should match it (entirely) so this is a regex you can use:

```
"/foo/bar/baz".replace(/(\/[^\/]*).*/, "$1")
```

it will capture a forward slash, followed by any non-forward slash symbol (exactly what you've done) and then `.*` will match anything until the end of the string (just to replace the entire string)